# How do you specify attributes for a LayoutManager assigned via RecyclerView's 'layoutManager' attribute?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

According to Google's [RecyclerView documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#attr_android.support.v7.recyclerview:layoutManager), you can set a specific `LayoutManager` from within a layout file by specifying its class name in the `RecyclerView`'s 'layoutManager' attribute.  It also specifically mentions `LayoutManager` has a constructor which accepts an `AttributeSet`.

My question is since you're specifying the `LayoutManager` via an attribute on the `RecyclerView`'s element, and not as its own element, where/how do you set the attributes targeted for the `LayoutManager` itself?

My guess is you add them directly to the `RecyclerView` element as well. This would make sense as inside the `RecyclerView`'s constructor, when it instantiates the `LayoutManager` specified in the 'layoutManager' attribute, it could simply pass through the same `AttributeSet` that was passed in to it. However, this is only a guess.

Here's an example of what I'm thinking is the correct way:

```
<MyRecyclerView
    app:layoutManager=".MyLayoutManager"
    app:attrOnlyUsedByRecyclerView="I'm used by MyRecyclerView"
    app:attrOnlyUsedByLayoutManager="I'm used by MyLayoutManager" />
```

Note how all three attributes are technically set on the `MyRecyclerView` element, but the thinking is the third attribute is ignored by, and passed through from `MyRecyclerView`'s constructor into `MyLayoutManager`'s constructor.

I'm trying to build a demo app to test that theory out now, but in the meantime, can anyone clarify for sure, or at least point me in the right direction if this is incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on a little testing it does seems that you can just apply the relevant attributes directly to the `RecyclerView` element and they will be passed through to the `LayoutManager`.

For example, the relevant constructor for `LinearLayoutManager` is:

```
/**
 * Constructor used when layout manager is set in XML by RecyclerView attribute
 * "layoutManager". Defaults to vertical orientation.
 *
 * @attr ref android.support.v7.recyclerview.R.styleable#RecyclerView_android_orientation
 * @attr ref android.support.v7.recyclerview.R.styleable#RecyclerView_reverseLayout
 * @attr ref android.support.v7.recyclerview.R.styleable#RecyclerView_stackFromEnd
 */
public LinearLayoutManager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr,
                           int defStyleRes) {
    Properties properties = getProperties(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    setOrientation(properties.orientation);
    setReverseLayout(properties.reverseLayout);
    setStackFromEnd(properties.stackFromEnd);
    setAutoMeasureEnabled(true);
}
```

...and here's how you specify the 'stackFromEnd' attribute for the `LayoutManager`. (Note how it's set it on the `RecyclerView` element even though it's destined for the `LayoutManager`.)

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
    app:stackFromEnd="true" />
```

Comment: Perfect!  I just clarified your text a little to drive home the points specifically and I'm marking yours as accepted.  Thanks!  Please make sure to vote this question up too if you feel it adds value to the site.